# Proving the integral $\int{1\over \sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx$ via substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

$\int{1\over \sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx$

How do I solve this without $\sin$ or $\cos$ substitution? I want to try using $u$ substitution because I feel like it will be more intuitive for me. So far, I have tried to make the function to the power of a negative exponent:

${(\sqrt{1-x^2})}^{-1}$

I tried to do $u$ $=$ $1-x^2$, and do the substitution method, but I keep getting the wrong answer; I'm trying to use this indefinite integral to solve a definite one from $1/2$ to $\sqrt{3}$/$2$.

I'd rather not use trigonometric substitution because I want to do this assuming I don't already know that this is the derivative of $\sin^{-1}x$.

Comment: Have you tried using integration by parts?

Comment: I don't see how you can get around using trigonometric functions since the integral's solution is one too.

Comment: If you use $u = 1-x^2,$, then $du = -2x \,dx$.  So to replace dx, you need $dx= \frac {du}{-2x}.$ But then you need to define $-2x$ in terms of $u = 1-x^2$.  Your best route is to use $x = \sin \theta$ or $x = \cos \theta.$  Say we pick $x= \sin \theta$.  Then $dx = \cos \theta.$ And we have the integral $\int \frac{\cos \theta}{\sqrt{\cos \theta}}\,d\theta$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution

Comment: @amWhy Why $sin$ or $cos$ specifically? What's the logic behind that? That's the thing that confuses me.

Comment: I meant that we have the integral $\int \frac{\cos\theta}{\sqrt{\cos^2 \theta}}\,d\theta$

Comment: Sajjib, because we can then take advantage of the identity $\cos^2 \theta = 1-\sin^2 \theta$, or $\sin^2 \theta = 1-\cos^2 \theta$.

Comment: You also can use the substitution $x=\tanh t$ in order to use the identity $1-\tanh^2t=\dfrac1{\cosh^2t}$.

Comment: @amWhy Oh, ok that makes sense. But how would someone know to do that just by looking at the question? Do you mean that you have to know the inverse trig functions etc. in order to solve this?

Comment: @SajjadAbbas There is a standard set of trigonometric substitutions to apply when you see square roots, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution)

Comment: Yes.  Given $\int \frac{\cos \theta}{\sqrt{\cos^2 \theta}}\,d\theta$, we have $\int d\theta =  \theta + C$.  And since $x= \sin \theta$, we know that $ \theta = \sin^{-1}(x)$.  So our result is $\sin^{-1) x + C.$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch  Those trig substitutions apply also even when one does not see square roots.

Comment: @amWhy You are right, thanks

Comment: If you'd like, @SajjadAbbas, I can write up an answer.  Else, perhaps you'd like to consolidate what you've learned, and answer your own question?  Glad to have helped.

Comment: Also, @SajjadAbbas, this is consistent with the fact that the derivative of $\sin^{-1} x + C$ is $\frac 1{1-x^2}$.  One doesn't need to know this derivative to use given trig substitution to discover that the given integral is in fact $\sin^{-1} x + C$.

Comment: @amWhy Ok most of what you said makes sense, thanks for all the help. Just one last thing - you said you don't need to know the derivative, but is there anything else you do need to solve this - such as the substitutions one of the comments referred to.

Comment: The link provided by @MaximilianJanisch is awesome: It explains and develops the most frequently used trig substitutions.  I'll repeat the link [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution).  Most basically, it amounts to knowing a few trig identities.

Answer (score 6):

Let $y(x)$ be defined on $(-1,1)$ as

$$y(x)=\int_0^x \frac1{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt\tag1$$

Note that $y(0)=0$.

---

Differentiating $(1)$, we find that

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

whence we see that

$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\sqrt{1-x^2}\tag2$$

Note that $x'(0)=1$.

---

Differentiating $(2)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}&=-\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,\frac{dx}{dy}\\\\
&=-x\tag3
\end{align}$$

---

The general solution to the ODE of $(3)$ is $x(y)=A\sin(y)+B\cos(y)$.  Given that $x(0)=0$ and $x'(0)=1$, we find that $x(y)=\sin(y)$.  This implies that $y(x)$ is the inverse function of the sine function.

Denoting this inverse function $y(x)=\arcsin(x)$ yields the result

$$\int_0^x \frac1{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt=\arcsin(x)$$

Comment: +1 elegant answer Mark

Comment: @LostInSpace Thank you!  Much appreciate your note!

Answer (score 0):

Try the self similar substitution 
 $$x=\frac{1-t}{1+t},\quad t\ge 0$$
$$\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-{{x}^{2}}}}dx}=-\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}\left( 1+t \right)}dt}=-2\int{\frac{1}{\left( 1+{{u}^{2}} \right)}du}$$

Answer (score 0):

It is not really possible to avoid a trigonometry-less solution, as the antiderivative is $\arcsin$ and nothing else and is not expressible as a rational function (though it has a logarithmic expression in the imaginary numbers).

The nice solution by @logo is right, but strictly speaking it should also require a substitution such as $u=\tan \theta$.

In fact,

$$\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$ should be considered an elementary integral as it appears in a table of derivatives of the common functions, just like, say, $\dfrac1x$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the inverse function theorem, you know that the antiderivative will be a solution of the ODE

$$y'=\sqrt{1-y^2}.$$

This should ring the bell of the sine function, for which we know that $(\sin y)'=\cos y$ and $\cos y=\sqrt{1-\sin^2y}$.

Then,

$$x=\sin y\iff y=\sin^{-1}x.$$

Answer (score 0):

To avoid trig substitutions, apply $x=i t $ instead

\begin{align}\int{1\over \sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx
=&\int{i\over \sqrt{1+t^2}}\,dt= i \ln\left(t +\sqrt{1+t^2}\right)\\
=&\ i \ln\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}-i x\right)
= i \ln\bigg( e^{-i\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}\bigg)\\
=& \ \tan^{-1}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
\end{align}